# Attaching a Custom Attribute with Variable Custom Data to Class Properties in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, propertygrid

I have the following code taken from the thread:
[TypeConverter reuse in PropertyGrid .NET winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500880/typeconverter-reuse-in-propertygrid-net-winforms)

The code sample is from the reply to the above thread by Simon Mourier

```
public class Animals
{
    // both properties have the same TypeConverter, but they use different custom attributes
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ListTypeConverter))]
    [ListTypeConverter(new [] { "cat", "dog" })]
    public string Pets { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ListTypeConverter))]
    [ListTypeConverter(new [] { "cow", "sheep" })]
    public string Others { get; set; }
}

// this is your custom attribute
// Note attribute can only use constants (as they are added at compile time), so you can't add a List object here
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ListTypeConverterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ListTypeConverterAttribute(string[] list)
    {
        List = list;
    }

    public string[] List { get; set; }
}

// this is the type converter that knows how to use the ListTypeConverterAttribute attribute
public class ListTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => true;

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        // the context contains the property descriptor
        // the property descriptor has all custom attributes defined on the property
        // just get it (with proper null handling)
        var choices = context.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<ListTypeConverterAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.List;
        if (choices != null)
        {
            list.AddRange(choices);
        }
        return new StandardValuesCollection(list);
    }
}
```

This approach seems to be possible as I have also seen it referenced in the following two threads:
http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/01/10/dynamic-attributes-in-c.aspx
[StringConverter GetStandardValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046026/stringconverter-getstandardvaluecollection?rq=1)

I can find the properties with ListTypeConverter custom attribute in the Animal class, and iterate through them

```
        var props = context.Instance.GetType().GetProperties().Where(
        prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ListTypeConverterAttribute))).ToList();
```

The issue I am having is that the code provided by Simon and the others requires the context.PropertyDescriptor, and in my case

```
context.PropertyDescriptor == null
```

How can I find the Animal class property that invoked the ListTypeConverter so that I can return the proper custom attribute list in the

```
return new StandardValuesCollection(list);
```

Comment: Is your code running in the Winforms standard property grid? PropertyDescriptor shouldn't be null. What is the full type name of `context`?

Comment: The Animal class is a nested class: RTS > Animals
The RTS class derives from ICustomTypeDescritor which is used to hide/show properties at runtime by modyfying the PropertyDescriptorCollection.

Comment: (context == null).ToString() is False / 
context.ToString() is System.Windows.Controls.WpfPropertyGrid.PropertyItem+ComponentContext / 
context.GetType().FullName is System.Windows.Controls.WpfPropertyGrid.PropertyItem+ComponentContext / 
context.GetType().Attributes.ToString() is AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, NestedPrivate, BeforeFieldInit

Comment: context.GetType().CustomAttributes.ToString() is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData] / 
context.GetType().GetProperties().ToString() is System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] / 

(context.PropertyDescriptor == null).ToString() is True

Comment: `WpfPropertyGrid` is **not** the Windows form property grid. I don't know about that thing but it's probably not fuly compatible the the Winforms one.

Comment: I am aware that it is not the same thing. I did not think though that any incompatibility issue might arise at something as basic as the PropertyDescriptor. As I am able to retrieve the properties, is there any other way to flag the actual  property invoking the TypeDescriptor? Also, is there any way to add the WpfPropertyGrid tag to this question; I don't want to repost it.

Comment: When you're aware of something important, it's good to put it in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190785/discussion-between-pbrenek-and-simon-mourier).

Comment: I believe the question was tagged with Wpf and PropertyGrid but I agree; it should have been stated in the question itself for more clarity.